# How do I set up debugging in visual code for a large c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner in c++ and vs-code but have been tasked to use/develop an existing c++ project (I have used python and sublime before this).

I want to be able to configure vs code so that I can easily debug and compile code without to much hassle.

Currently, this is the way I do it:

- Make some change in the code, for example in $basedir/src/folder1/file.cpp
- Go to $basedir in the terminal, and run
- a) make
- b) *wait for it to go through a bunch of folders to find a file that has been changed.*
- c) cd $basedir/programs/dawn; make clean; make
- And finally to run the project a type: `$basedir/programs/project/projectname inputfile.json`

What I want to do is to just press F5 (for debugging, or ctrl+F5 to run), but I don't know how to set everything up is vs code. Can someone help me?

These are my configuration files:
In c_cpp_properties.json I have referenced two other projects, but I also have to add the current project include-directory in order for vs-code to not complain about include-file, etc (I thought it would automatically find files in the project with `${workspaceFolder}/**`)

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "~/otherproject1/include/",
            "~/otherproject2/include/",
            "~/Documents/projectname/include"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}

{
```

tasks.json

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "cd ${workspaceFolder};",
            "make;",
            "make clean -C programs/projectname;",
            "make -C programs/projectname;",
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "/usr/bin"
        }
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

launch.json

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "g++ build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/programs/projectname inputfile.json",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "g++ build active file",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides great tutorials for setting up your debugging environment.

Please check these tutorials:

[VSCode CPP Debug](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug)

[Config mingW and GCC Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_debug-helloworldcpp)

What's apparent in your config is that you have missed the `.exe` here

```
"program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}", //< -- wrong
"program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe", // < -- correct
```

and locate your debugger and add the path in here:

```
"miDebuggerPath": "C:\\path\\to\\gdb.exe",
```

To start debugging just hit `F5`. For Building, hit `CTRL + SHIFT + B` and select your build-task.

Comment: Thank you for the links, by they only show simple hello-world projects, and I using a large project where I have to run `make` at a bunch of places. I tried to add `make` for `args` in `tasks.json`, but this did not work. I also hardcoded the program path and name, but got a bunch of errors. Any tips?

Comment: Read up on the tasks structure. Your command should be make, not usr/bin/g++